# Home Networking - Wired & Wireless Router Complexities

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Whilst not being a home network expert I will try my best to show what I am trying to achieve and ask you guys for some input / best practice.

Network Overview:

[image]

The Icotera i5801 gateway has an internal 192.168.0.1 and gives a static Lease 192.168.0.2 to FVS336Gv3 (192.168.1.1) which I use as the main router / firewall / DHCP server and fail-over for WAN1 to WAN2.

I was previously using the TP Link Archer C7 as the router but would like to have VPN access to multiple computers / servers, therefore I decided to use the C7 as a WAP plugged into LAN port on the FVS336Gv3. The TP Link C7 is then (192.168.2.1) and the DHCP Server for all wireless devices.

The Icotera i5801 gateway was put in the DMZ and my ISP gave me a fixed IP address. The FVS336Gv3 then handles all routing and port forwarding needed for my IP security cameras and port that I need to be accessible from outside the network.

Problems I currently encounter / Question I have are:

- Only see WAN IP from Fiber Gateway not fixed IP address (85.x.x.x) - can this be fixed or should I just leave it as 192.168.0.2 (the static lease from the fiber gateway)
- I cannot access the wireless router on subnet 192.168.2.1 from subnet 192.168.1.1 and from what I have read that is not possible to fix
- Would it be better to have the wireless router as DHCP server on the same 192.168.1.1 subnet and just restrict the DHCP address range for wired & wireless?
- Wireless devices on subnet 192.168.1.1 cannot access music from the WAM250 hub
- I assume this is because of the subnet issue and if they were all on the same subnet they would be fine?
- If I needed to expand wireless coverage in house with 1-2 extra WAP I am concerns that I will run out of IP address' in the 192.168.1.1 subnet that is why I wanted to use 192.168.2.1 as wireless only subnet and maybe 192.168.3.1 and 4.1 as new wireless subnets.

Generally based on what I am trying to achieve here what is the best network setup here?

Comment: A very similiar questions was answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/1162149/home-lan-with-two-subnets-only-one-subnet-can-see-the-other/1162177#1162177

Comment: TLDR: try to remove the NAT routers that are inside your firewall and replace with switches.  Note many NAT routers can be put into bridge or access point mode which makes the effectively switches.